# How to sort a date field that is a String

Tags: sorting, jasper-reports

I am having problem in generating sorted jasper report by date, since the date is a String.

[image: example]

I have converted String Date to Java Date, but confused with the sorting. Still the report generated is not sorted

```
<field name="DEF" class="java.lang.String"/>
<sortField name="DEF"/>
<textField>
  <reportElement x="480" y="0" width="85" height="20" uuid="dcfb14be-5d9b-4d0e-9565-c4f290064faa">
  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.spreadsheet.connectionID" value="06d913e9-5da9-44c8-8111-91150d16384d"/>
  </reportElement>
  <textElement>
    <font fontName="Lucida Bright"/>
  </textElement>
  <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy").format(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse((($F{DEF} != null && $F{DEF}.length() == 9) ? $F{DEF}.replace(" ", "-") : "")))]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: If the data is coming from a database, typically you'd (a) leave the field as a SQL date field and (b) put an `ORDER BY` clause on the SQL statement. If you can coerce the data to be queried using SQL that would also work. Dropping to Java to sort strings by first converting to objects seems like a cumbersome workaround.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need to sort on variabile, sort type [`Variable`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/SortFieldTypeEnum.html)

1. Create a variable (that is Comparable) to sort on, you can parse the String to `java.util.Date` (assuming your string format is "ddMMM yy")

   ```
   <variable name="date" class="java.util.Date">
       <variableExpression><![CDATA[new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy").parse($F{DEF})]]></variableExpression>
   </variable>
   ```
2. Then set the `sortField` to the variabile name with type `Variable`

   ```
   <sortField name="date" type="Variable"/>
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Petter for the reply. But I already tried this way. The report was giving error. 
Below is the answer which worked for me.

         `<variable name="THE_DATE" class="java.util.Date">`

    `<variableExpression><![CDATA[new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yy").format(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse((($F{DEF} != null && $F{DEF}.length() == 9) ? $F{DEF}.replace(" ", "-") : ""))))]]></variableExpression>
 </variable>`

Comment: yes without casting it in Date it was giving error as date variable type is date and new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse($F{DEF}) returns string.

Comment: @Tabani the solution is to sort by variable, naturally you need to adjust pattern if data does not comply to dd-MM-yyyy in question your data was formated like this

Comment: @Tabani I have edit the post slight i believe your pattern is "dd MMM yy", there is no need to do all the parsing your are doing